# Convert Date from Google forms to typescript

Tags: typescript, date

Currently, I have a google form connected with a google spreadsheet. Whenever I get a response, google sheets registers the date with the following format:

```
20/02/2023 18:58:59
```

I would like to know how can I convert this in Typescript.

When doing the dev of the website, I managed to work around it like so:

```
datestr = '20/02/2023 18:58:59'
datestr = Date(datestr)
d = new Date(datestr)
```

But of course, when building for production I get so many errors, first of all, the `Date(d)` function can't be called because `Date()` does not expect an argument. But if I do `new Date(datestr)` directly, it will just return `Invalid date`.

Any ideas on how to handle this? If possible, use built-in types to avoid handling the date myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this function:

```
const strToDate = (dtStr) => {
    if (!dtStr) return null;
    const dateParts = dtStr.split('/');
    const timeParts = dateParts[2].split(' ')[1].split(':');
    dateParts[2] = dateParts[2].split(' ')[0];
    return new Date(
        +dateParts[2],
        dateParts[1] - 1,
        +dateParts[0],
        timeParts[0],
        timeParts[1],
        timeParts[2]
    );
};
const dtStr = '20/02/2023 18:58:59';
const date = strToDate(dtStr)
```

Comment: I guess doing something custom like this is my only solution for now. Just bit surprised there is nothing built-in, considering this format is Oracle DB format. So it's quite used.

Answer (score 0):

1.you can import datepipe from angular common module
ie.
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';

2.then create constructor for this
ie.

```
constructor(
   
        public datepipe: DatePipe
    ) {}
```

3.then call your date like

```
let date = this.datepipe.transform(yourdate.toISOString(), 'yyyy-MM-dd');
```

Comment: Didn't mention, but I'm using Vue3.